# Accessing shared preferences in two Android Applications

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have two projects with the same signature and the same share user id set. I can access shared preferences across the two applications if I explicitly specify the two applications to run on the same process, however if I do not specify the process in the manifest of the two applications, I am not able to access data across applications.
How can I access the shared preferences across the two applications if they run on separate processes?

Comment: Thanks for the information. You have a question?

Comment: @dotvav Edited the Question

Answer (score 1):

I think its wise the two applications store the data from shared preferences into an sqlite database. You then use a contentProvider to share the data across the two apps.

Forexample apps like facebook, whatsup use the contacts stored in the phone by using the content provider of the contacts app.

Read more about content providers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay! using this code in Application 1 ( with package name is "com.sharedpref1" ) to store data with Shared Preferences.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("demostring", strShareValue);
        editor.commit();
```

And using this code in Application 2 to get data from Shared Preferences in Application 1. We can get it because we use MODE_WORLD_READABLE in application 1:

```
try {
            con = createPackageContext("com.sharedpref1", 0);
            SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                    "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
            displaySharedValue.setText(data);

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
        }
```

More information please visit this URL: http://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2012/03/share-data-across-application-in.html

**From developer.android**
This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Creating world-readable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver, and Service. There are no guarantees that this access mode will remain on a file, such as when it goes through a backup and restore. File creation mode: allow all other applications to have read access to the created file.

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE has now been deprecated.